# Websockets on Atmosphere.js keep closing , possible bringing the server down

Tags: amazon-web-services, gwt, websocket, atmosphere.js, jsr356

We have a GWT application deployed on AWS ELB. 
We're using an Atmosphere.js and websocket set up to get number of live users every second to the UI.
I keep seeing this error on the UI:

> Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is,
>   with no close frame being sent). - wasClean: false
>
> and on the server side I see
>
> 02-Feb-2017 09:27:08.486 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
>   org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint.onError   java.io.EOFException
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.doRead(NioServletInputStream.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.read(AbstractServletInputStream.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:647)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDIT : 
Listener configuration:
[image]

At times when there is a lot of activity on this page, the server eventually crashes.

What could be the cause for the exception I see on the server side?

Comment: Please include the information about how your ELB listeners are configured. Also, have you considered using an ALB instead?

Comment: @MarkB I added a link to the listener configuration i found

Comment: @MarkB What is an ALB ?

Comment: ALB stands for Application Load Balancer. It's the newer version of an ELB that supports web sockets. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/